# AJAX success with submit not found

Tags: jquery, ajax, submit

I need to use a submit, but when i execute AJAX function this work fine but not execute the success event. I execute the next function on sumbit.

```
       <input id="btnReg" type="submit" value="Registrarme" />

       $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Handler/General.ashx?mn=Registrar&n=" + (new Date()).getMinutes() + "-" + (new Date()).getSeconds(),
            data: JSON.stringify(jSON),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            //dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                var lblError = document.getElementById('lblError');
                if (data == -2) {
                    lblError.innerHTML = "El código de promoción es invalido.";
                }
                else if (data > 0) {
                    var btnRegistrar = document.getElementById('btnRegistrar');
                    lblError.innerHTML = "El usuario ha sido registrado con exito.<br />En breve te llegará un correo con la liga para que puedas activar tu cuenta.<br/><br/> Gracias por tu paciencia";
                    btnRegistrar.style.display = "none";
                }
                else {
                    lblError.innerHTML = "Este usuario ya ha sido registrado.<br/>Por favor verifica los datos";
                }
            }
        });
```

On Success event i have to display message, but not found.

When i use a button, i don´t have any problem, the function execute correct, but i don´t understand why, if i execute the same process.

You have any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking/what issue you are having.  Can you clarify?  Are you receiving a javascript error?